# How insert variable in JS

Tags: javascript

I need help, how to insert variable n as XX. Variable n is number, for example 3 and I need to get this number to `document.form1.any3.value;` is it possible? Thanks for advice

```
function pokus(n){
    var any1 = document.form1.anyXX.value;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use square bracket notation:

```
function pokus(n){
    var any1 = document.form1['any'+n].value;
}
```

Comment: If OP decides to use jslint, it will complain about this method. http://jslinterrors.com/a-is-better-written-in-dot-notation/

Comment: OK, thanks for your contribution in any case.